# LDAP message structure

Tags: networking, ldap, protocols

I'm trying to understand the LDAP message structure, particularly the `searchResEntry` type in order to do some parsing.  Using Wireshark as a guide, I have a general understanding but I can't find more specifics on the actual data structure.  For example, it appears that each block starts with

```
 0x30 0x84 0x0 0x0
```

Then from there, there is some variability on the remaining bytes before the actual data for the block.  For example the first 17 bytes of a `searchResEntry` is

```
30 84 00 00 0b 8f 02 01 0c 64 84 00 00 0b 86 04 3b

30 84 00 00 - block header
0b 8f - size of entire searchResEntry remaining
02 - I believe represents a type code where the next byte (01) is a length and 0c is the messageId.
64 84 00 00 - No idea
0b 86 - size of entire searchResEntry remaining
04 - some type code
3b - length of block data
```

But then other blocks that begin with `30 84 00 00` are not 17 bytes long.

I've looked at rfc4511 but they just provide an unhelpful notation that doesn't actually describe the what the bytes mean.

```
searchResultEntry ::= [APPLICATION 4] SEQUENCE {
             objectName      LDAPDN,
             attributes      PartialAttributeList }
```

I've also looked at Wireshark's `packet-ldap.c` but it is very hard to follow.  I wouldn't think it would be this hard to find a good description of the data structure layout and associated flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP protocol is encoded according to the ASN.1 BER encoding rules which is a standard defined by ITU. Full specifications are here: https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf